# Pod install выдает ошибку

Tags: cocoa, xcode

в проекте пытаюсь добавить новые модули через cocoapod. В pod файл добавил нужный модуль. В строке пишу pod install а в ответ получаю

```
[!] Pod::Executable pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details
    git pull <remote> <branch>
If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:
    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

Проект на bitbucket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего не правильно установлены гемы и подсы. Попробуйте переустановить кокоуподс. Лучше через brew там все просто.

Comment: Как не странно переустановка помогла. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Очень похоже что не была выполнена команда

> [sudo] pod setup